# Admobs needs permissions which I already have

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to use AdMobs on Android. This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.krinsen.javadocreader"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.SimpleApp"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_about"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Javadoc" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.DocTypeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".ui.SearchableJavadocActivity" />
        </activity>
<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

This is my view:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/ads"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
    ads:testDevices="@string/test_devices"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

And I have admob library up to date.
I am still getting this strange error in logcat:

```
INTERNET permissions must be enabled in AndroidManifest.xml
```

I have internet permission. My app uses internet and uses it very well. Only ads don't want to cooperate. Where I can look for a bug?

Comment: post your manifest file.

Answer (score 5):

i think you have added the `permissions` in wrong place , add the full `AndroidManifest.xml` file ,

instead , your manifestFile should look something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.novaapps.android.couponmanager"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:name=".CouponManager"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

        </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

and in your `Layout` you should include following `namespace` code in the `Layout` tag :

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

**NOTE : refer this** [**tutorial**](http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/integrating-admob-in-your-android-app-and-make-money/) **for more details**

Comment: This is not the problem. I tried `<uses-permission>` before as well as after `<application>` tag. `xmlns` can be in view, not necessary in container. Btw your idea didn't help:/

Comment: try to clean your project and relaunch it again

Comment: I already cleaned project... couple of times, as well as restarting Eclipse, checked on another phone... still no idea:/

Comment: Try creating a new project and see if the same problem exists. Eclipse and Google Android SDK are not exactly bug-free, to put it mildly...

Comment: @sennin : did you see the **tutorial** in the **NOTE** tag in my answer ?

Comment: To me, in Manifest: <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/> then I add necessary meta-data tags in between application tags of the Manifest file. Also I add:     <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

Answer (score 1):

Please try to copy this then check what happened as i didn't find any error in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xChinmoy.babywallpaperhd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.xChinmoy.babywallpaperhd.BabyWallPaperActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the view is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/advw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a150cd49f90925f"
    ads:backgroundColor="#FFFF00"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    ads:refreshInterval="30"
    ads:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
    android:visibility="visible" />                    
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I have created it yesterday and perfectly display the add, and admob jar version is 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

sennin,

admob needs the **adUnitId** of yours to work with your account.

Get the admob adUnitId that is linked with your account and use it.

Don't forget to add **ad:testDevices**  in XML if you are currently in development.

Rest are fine with Chinmoy's code snippet.

Create an application entry in admob and get the adUnitId from settings of that entry.

Hopes this will help you.

Comment: Houcine has given a very nice link for tutorial. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add the below lines in your `Manifest.xml` file outside the `application` tag.

> ```
> <meta-data
>     android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS"
>     android:value="true" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Just add the last two lines.I solved it by this.

Comment: It was in my old project. Now I think that is reasonable. In my implementation lacks `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. But now it isn't required if I remember. Can someone explain this? In old implementation it was necessary? Is there even something like "old implementation" in here?